# What XML should I use to obtain network usage information from the VMware SDK

Tags: xml, soap, sdk, vmware

I have tried going though several iterations of this and I am hoping I am just looking at the wrong thing entirely or I might just be blind. :-)  So the basic parameters in grabbing info from the SDK are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:vim25" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:RetrieveProperties>
      <ns1:_this type="PropertyCollector">propertyCollector</ns1:_this>
      <ns1:specSet>
        <ns1:propSet>
          <ns1:type>DistributedVirtualSwitch</ns1:type>
          <ns1:all>true</ns1:all>
        </ns1:propSet>
        <ns1:objectSet>
          <ns1:obj type="Folder">group-d1</ns1:obj>
          <ns1:skip>false</ns1:skip>
          <ns1:selectSet xsi:type="TraversalSpec">
            <name>FolderTraversalSpec</name>
            <type>Folder</type>
            <path>childEntity</path>
            <skip>false</skip>
            <selectSet>
              <name>FolderTraversalSpec</name>
            </selectSet>
            <selectSet>
              <name>DataCenterVMTraversalSpec</name>
            </selectSet>
          </ns1:selectSet>
          <ns1:selectSet xsi:type="TraversalSpec">
            <name>DataCenterVMTraversalSpec</name>
            <type>Datacenter</type>
            <path>networkFolder</path>
            <skip>false</skip>
            <selectSet>
              <name>FolderTraversalSpec</name>
            </selectSet>
          </ns1:selectSet>
        </ns1:objectSet>
      </ns1:specSet>
    </ns1:RetrieveProperties>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is supposed to give me all data for every Virtual Switch defined.  And it does... but where there should be some metrics about network utilization all I get are 0's.  Specifically in runtime.resourceRuntimeInfo.

I have tried getting at it by getting all data from the networkFolder and grabbing DistributedVirtualPortgroup entries... I have switched it up to vmFolder and grabbed quite a bit of useful data from VirtualMachine.  Specifically in the pathsets of: guest and summary.  I have even tried to get some sort of network statistics from the hostFolder and grabbing the ComputeResource type.

None of it produces traffic in/out/total type stats... ideally I would like to get it by port... but at this point I would settle for just getting rolled up virtual switch data at the moment.

I am open to using SNMP, but I would need to provide instructions on how to set up the virtual switches for monitoring then... about the only thing I cannot do is use the command line.

Any help would be much appreciated as any knowledge on the specifics of network usage statistics in VMware seem to be pretty deeply buried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never got why the above XML gave me all 0's where it looked like there should be a performance summary, but I did get finally make some headway on figuring out how to properly query the VMWare API.  Unfortunately, using PHP was a bit trying as the implementations for VMWare tended toward the incomplete side and weren't well documented.

So I made a PHP-based API that uses RAW XML (since I couldn't get the various SOAP libraries to consistently give me what I needed).

https://github.com/matt-o-matic/PHP-VMWare-API-Class

Specifically, to answer my question above... it is a multi-step process to get at network usage on any device within VMWare.  First, you must find out the ID of the device.  The XML above in the question does that bit nicely.  Just look for the obj_id in the output and you'll have the object id.

From there it gets a little trickier.  You'll also have to know the object TYPE in VMWare.  In my case:

- VM Guests = VirtualMachine
- VM Hosts = ComputeResource
- Virtual Switches = DistributedVirtualSwitch

To get a list of metric IDs that are supported for that object:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:vim25">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:QueryAvailablePerfMetric>
            <urn:_this>PerfMgr</urn:_this>
            <urn:entity type="VirtualMachine">vm-1844</urn:entity>
        </urn:QueryAvailablePerfMetric>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You'll get a bunch of ID and instance pairs.  You'll need both eventually... but for now let's just take a look at the IDs.  You can get a detailed view of what the metric is by calling the function described below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:vim25">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:QueryPerfCounter>
            <urn:_this>PerfMgr</urn:_this>
            <urn:counterId>125</urn:counterId>
            <urn:counterId>133</urn:counterId>
            <urn:counterId>143</urn:counterId>
        </urn:QueryPerfCounter>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You can put in as many of the counterIds as you want... or just put 1 in.  It will work either way.  In my instance, 143 is the ID for the total network in and out for that VM object.  Grabbing the telemetry for that ID/instance (in this case the instance was blank) for that object is as simple as:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:vim25">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:QueryPerf>
            <urn:_this>PerfMgr</urn:_this>
            <urn:querySpec>
                <urn:entity type="VirtualMachine">vm-1844</urn:entity>
                <urn:startTime>2020-05-22T22:30:00Z</urn:startTime>
                <urn:startTime>2020-05-22T23:30:00Z</urn:startTime>
                <urn:metricId>
                    <urn:counterId>143</urn:counterId>
                    <urn:instance></urn:instance>
                </urn:metricId>
                <urn:format>csv</urn:format>
            </urn:querySpec>
        </urn:QueryPerf>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Note that the dates are in GMT.  Other than that, fairly straight-forward to get some data back.  More information is in the VMWare documentation if you want to brave all that.  Also, a detailed look through SoapUI really helped me figure a lot of this out (more so than the documentation if I'm honest).

Just remember to set the vmware_soap_session cookie once you log in for any other calls in SoapUI.

Hope this helps anyone else searching for this answer.